# What does Internet Explorer Version Suffix = CO mean?

Tags: internet-explorer

I was checking my Internet explorer version after hearing about a big security bug in IE and I noticed that IE stated the following information:

Version: 11.0.9600.17105 **CO**

Update Versions: 11.0.7 (KB2964358)

...

I couldn't find any information about what the CO at the end of my version meant. Does it mean that I have an older version of IE and need to update it (I have automatic version install checked)? Or does it indicate some sort of setting I have on IE?

Answer (score 7):

> • All versions of Internet Explorer 5.0 (and later versions) that are
>   customized with Microsoft Internet Explorer Administration Kit (IEAK)
>   include one of the following strings after the version number. To view
>   this information, click About on the Help menu:
>
> IC = Internet content provider
>  IS = Internet service provider
>  
>   **CO = Corporate administrator**

Source: [MS KB969393: Information about Internet Explorer versions](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/969393)