# What is "IS" suffix in IE11 version?

Tags: internet-explorer

I'm running Windows 10 Pro (64) and stock IE11 with "Install new versions automatically" enabled.

My current version is: 11.545.10586.0IS

What does IS suffix mean?

I'm having a problem with font-awesome.io, and wondering if "IS" suffix have to do anything with it.
Specifically, icon's on font-awesome.io won't render unless I turn off "Enable Protected Mode" in Internet Settings. On my other computer without "IS" suffix - FA is rendered fine with or without protected mode enabled.

Is there an option to install "non-IS" version?

I installed IE using "Programs and Features" -> "Turn Windows features on or off".

Comment: Either installations of Windows a regionalized version (Chinese, N, ect.)?

Comment: I don't think so. It might be "N", but I thought "N" is a feature-set, not a region.

Comment: You need to verify with 100% certainity.  Windows 10 N Professional is a regional product, its not typically sold to North America customers, only EU customers.  Anything less then 100% confirmation one way or another is not helpful.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What does Internet Explorer Version Suffix = CO mean?](http://superuser.com/questions/752630/what-does-internet-explorer-version-suffix-co-mean)

Comment: As explained in the marked duplicate: IS = Internet service provider